# Change checkbox depends of <select>

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have select and if I choose something, then id of `<option>` is send to .php file and then I want to (after check something in database) check or uncheck checkbox. I have everything except last thing.
I wanted to do in that way:

```
if ($zmienna == 0) {

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name=nazwa]').attr('checked', true);       
});

    </script>   


    <?php
        }
        else {

        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name=nazwa]').attr('checked', false);      
});

    </script>   
        <?php
        }
```

But it don't want works;/

The problem is that if I paste

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name=nazwa]').attr('checked', true);      
});

    </script>
```

at once on head or somewhere else it works, but if I call it:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","info_o_klience.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And in info_o_klience.php I want to check if I have to check or uncheck checkbox and write

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name=nazwa]').attr('checked', true);      
});
```

With true or false it don't want works...

Comment: Have you tried `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` ? Also, your code would be neater if you had one opening script tag and document.ready, with PHP just changing the checked value.

Comment: UM, the Ajax call will not run the JavaScript returned...

Answer (score 0):

Barely could understand your question, and your code seems wrong by a number of issues, but you can try this:

```
$('input[name=nazwa]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @epascarello my bad. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and explained it better.